# Using numpy digitize output in scipy minimize problem

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to minimize the quadratic weighted kappa function using scipy minimize fmin Powell function.

The two functions `digitize_train` and `digitize_train2` gives 100% EXACT same results.

However, when I tried to use these functions with scipy minimize the second method fails.

I have been trying to debug the problem for hours, to my surprise despite the two functions being exact same the bumpy digitize function fails to give fmin Powell mimimization.

How to fix the error?

**Question**
How to use `numpy.digitize` in scipy `fmin_powell`?

## SETUP

```
# imports
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy.optimize import fmin_powell
from sklearn import metrics

# data
train_labels = [1,1,8,7,6,5,3,2,4,4]
train_preds = [0.1,1.2,8.9, 7.6, 5.5, 5.5, 2.99, 2.4, 3.5, 4.0]
guess_lst = (1.5,2.9,3.1,4.5,5.5,6.1,7.1)


# functions
# here I am trying the convert real numbers -inf to +inf to integers 1 to 8
def digitize_train(train_preds, guess_lst):
    (x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7) = list(guess_lst)   
    res = []
    for y in list(train_preds):
        if y < x1:
            res.append(1)
        elif y < x2:
            res.append(2)
        elif y < x3:
            res.append(3)
        elif y < x4:
            res.append(4)
        elif y < x5:
            res.append(5)
        elif y < x6:
            res.append(6)
        elif y < x7:
            res.append(7)
        else: res.append(8)
    return res

def digitize_train2(train_preds, guess_lst):
    return np.digitize(train_preds,guess_lst) + 1

# compare two functions
df = pd.DataFrame({'train_labels': train_labels,
                   'train_preds': train_preds,
                   'method_1': digitize_train(train_preds, guess_lst),
                   'method_2': digitize_train2(train_preds, guess_lst)
                    })

df
```

** NOTE: The two functions are exact same**

## Method 1: without numpy digitize runs fine

```
# using fmin_powel for method 1
def get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa(guess_lst):
    res = digitize_train(train_preds, guess_lst)
    return - metrics.cohen_kappa_score(train_labels, res,weights='quadratic')  

offsets = fmin_powell(get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa, guess_lst, disp = True)
print(offsets)
```

## Method 2: using numpy digitize fails

```
# using fmin_powell for method 2
def get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa2(guess_lst):
    res = digitize_train2(train_preds, guess_lst)
    return -metrics.cohen_kappa_score(train_labels, res,weights='quadratic')  

offsets = fmin_powell(get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa2, guess_lst, disp = True)
print(offsets)
```

How to use numpy digitize method?

## Update

As per suggestions I tried pandas cut, but still gives error.
`ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.`

```
# using fmin_powell for method 3
def get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa3(guess_lst):
    res = pd.cut(train_preds, bins=[-np.inf] + list(guess_lst) + [np.inf],
                        right=False)
    res = pd.Series(res).cat.codes + 1
    res = res.to_numpy()

    return -metrics.cohen_kappa_score(train_labels, res,weights='quadratic')  

offsets = fmin_powell(get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa3, guess_lst, disp = True)
print(offsets)
```

Comment: Looks like `pd.cut` would be a better choice for `digitize_train`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I tried using pandas cut, but still scipy function fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that during the minimization process, the value in `guest_lst` are not monotonically increasing anymore, one work around is to pass the `sorted` of `guest_lst` in `digitize` like:

```
def digitize_train2(train_preds, guess_lst):
    return np.digitize(train_preds,sorted(guess_lst)) + 1
```

and you get

```
# using fmin_powell for method 2
def get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa2(guess_lst):
    res = digitize_train2(train_preds, guess_lst)
    return -metrics.cohen_kappa_score(train_labels, res,weights='quadratic')  

offsets = fmin_powell(get_offsets_minimizing_train_preds_kappa2, guess_lst, disp = True)
print(offsets)
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: -0.990792
         Iterations: 2
         Function evaluations: 400
[1.5        2.7015062  3.1        4.50379942 4.72643334 8.12463415
 7.13652301]
```